# Apple Push Notification with Java SSL Socket

Tags: java, ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I am trying Apple Push Notification with Java 7. I am using linux.

I tried various libraries availble in java like JavaPNS, java-apns.

But getting Exception

> java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

I tried it with php code on same machine after following this blog http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Here is PHP code

http://pastebin.com/kMdVdk2F

How to make it work in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I was exporting both Certificate.cer + key.pem files as .p12. But it was wrong. We should generate .p12 by only exporting certificate.